# iOS: NSPredicate using NSDate to compare

Tags: ios, ios7, nsdate, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an `NSDate` attribute called `startDate` stored in the persistence store in the following format (picture below).

[image]

426174354 = July 04, 2014

I need to create (3) `NSFetchRequest` using predicates.

For `startDate`:

1. `fetchRequest1` using predicate(s) need to fetch everything that falls in today's date based on User's device time.
2. `fetchRequest2` using predicate(s) need to fetch everything that's in the past, meaning yesterday and before, based on User's device time.
3. `fetchRequest3` using predicate(s) need to fetch everything that's in the future, meaning starting tomorrow and after, based on User's device time.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getFetchPredicate:(NSUInteger)fetchRequestType
{
    NSDate *now = [self getcurrentTime:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    format.dateFormat = @"dd-MM-yyyy";
    format.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    NSString *stringDate = [format stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate *todaysDate = [format dateFromString:stringDate];
    //today's date is now a date without time. 

    NSMutableArray *subpredicates;

    if (fetchRequestType == 1)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredToday = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate == %@ ", todaysDate];
        [subpredicates addObject:subPredToday];
    }
    else if (fetchRequestType == 2)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredPast = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate < %@", todaysDate];
        [subpredicates addObject:subPredPast];
    }
    else if (fetchRequestType == 3)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredFuture = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", todaysDate];
        [subpredicates addObject:subPredFuture];
    }
    return subPredicates;
}

-(NSDate *)getcurrentTime:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDate *sourceDate = date;

    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

    NSDate* deviceDateWithTime = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate];
    return deviceDateWithTime;
}
```

The code above is not fetching the right objects from CoreData.  I have a feeling my predicates for comparison are incorrect.  I'm not sure how to convert the stored time in `startDate` to just Date format only and apply that in Predicates for comparison.  Any suggestions?

Comment: None of your fetch request types returns correct results?

Comment: Nope. Do I need to convert stored date to just Date only?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your notion of `todaysDate`. AFAIK, `NSDate` represents an absolute point in time, so your effort to create a "Date" without "Time" seems futile. And also the use of `NSDateFormatter` to set the dates is shaky.

I think you must create two different `NSDate` objects: `startOfCurrentDay` (e.g 00:00:00) and `endOfCurrentDay` (e.g 23:59:59) and personally I would do it by using an `NSCalendar`. If you do so, your fetch request predicates will be:

```
 if (fetchRequestType == 1)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredToday = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(startDate >= %@) AND (startDate <= %@)", startOfCurrentDay, endOfCurrentDay];
    }
    else if (fetchRequestType == 2)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredPast = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate < %@", startOfCurrentDay];
    }
    else if (fetchRequestType == 3)
    {
        NSPredicate *subPredFuture = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate > %@", endOfCurrentDay];
    }
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you!  Last question:  The values `426174354` for `startDate` that's stored in Core Data, what format is that in?  I don't think it's in seconds, is it?

Comment: It actually is: it's the number of seconds elapsed from the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT. You can find more in the [NSDate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks!  Perhaps you also know this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556123/nsfetchedresultscontroller-multiple-frcs-delegate-error-when-updating

Comment: @Sripathi Between keyword does not work with core data, it crashes the app.